# Send a Packet to Flash Object

Tags: c#, flash

I'm currently working on a flash game cheat tool, but I'm having trouble finding a way to directly send a packet to the flash shockwave object on Visual Studio using C#.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I tried:

```
string packet = "%xt%s%i#ai%-1%413%";
byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(packet);

axShockwaveFlash1.Send(send_buffer);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Questions that show no research, despite how much you may have done, generally are closed.  Add some code, or things you have tried and errors you've received to get better feedback.

Comment: I don't use Shockwave or C#, but a quick search turned up the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) for Adobe Air, which has a UDP socket example involving single packets. I'm surprised that a browser plugin can reach that low in the network stack.

Comment: @paqogomez I edited the question with what It tried.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".